# Armature seems to create a duplicate model when moving in Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, armature

[image: Dolphin]

[image]

Hi folks,

I'm a blender noob.  I decided to sculpt a dolphin.  A friend asked if I could quickly animate it.

I've previously added armature to humans and objects with no problem.  I usually use the "With Automatic weights" option.

However when I try and move the armature in pose mode afterwards I seem to get a funny duplicate of the dolphin appearing.

Any help would be appreciated.  The mesh is not great and I am still new to Blender so go easy on me.  It would be great if I could get this little critter to animate.

I've tried cleaning up the mesh (Merge by Distance) and recalculating the mesh.

I've included the file in the link above.  I hope someone can help.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! There is an issue with the file you provided, so I can't open it to check it out. Can you upload it again here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Also have you checked your modifiers? Is there a mirror on this object?

Comment: Hi. Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if you want to provide files for us to check. Random file sharing services won't keep them up long enough. Your questions and our answers might become useless, once the link to the file breaks.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I uploaded it on blend-exchange and modified the title a little bit.